# Calling Python functions/methods with zero arguments

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, class, methods

According to [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882), a function should take zero arguments when at all possible.

If we take a trivial example in Python with a function that does nothing more than add 2 to whatever is passed to it:

```
def add_two(x):
    return x + 2

>add_two(1)
3
```

The only way I can see that such a function can have zero arguments passed to it is by incorporating it into a class:

```
class Number(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def add_two(self):
        return self.x + 2

>n = Number(1)
>n.add_two()
3
```

It hardly seems worth the effort. Is there another way of achieving the no-argument function in this example?

Comment: I guess that who said that meant just that you should not have functions with 20 arguments. Of course in your case it's perfectly reasonable to have one argument.

Comment: just to echo's @nbro, in this case, it's just logical to assume that your function will have one argument.  This doesn't make the code any less clean.  If you want to make this an argument less function, you can always prompt for the argument.  Have the caller input the number to add two to by having the function prompt it (if the use-case allows such possibilities)

Comment: your method still took an argument `self`...

Comment: your constructor for `Number` took an argument

Answer (score 4):

> If we take a trivial example in Python with a function that does
>   nothing more than add 2 to whatever is passed to it:
>   ...
>   Is there another way of achieving the no-argument function in this
>   example?

In a word, no. 
In several words: by definition, your function takes an argument. There's no way to take an argument without taking an argument.

Comment: The only way to do something that is _passed_ to the function is to make the function take an argument.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yes, I'd accept that as an equivalent and more precise statement.

Comment: Technically, you could do "globals only", but that would be possibly the worst practice and entirely defeats the purpose of using functions.

(Would be kinda hilarious to see an entire application written that terribly though if you don't have to maintain it).

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh - yes, I thought of that, but it seemed unkind to even mention such a horror in connection with Bob Martin, who has done nothing whatsoever to deserve that indignity.

Answer (score 3):

**In General**

That is truly bad general advice, no argument methods are great for objects that modify the object in a way that requires **no** external data, or for functions that only interact with globals (you should really have minimal need to do this). In your case, you need to modify a given object with external data, and both objects are a builtin type (`int`).

In this case, just use a function with two arguments.

**Too Many Arguments**

Now, here is where the advice gets good. Say I need to do a complicated task, with numerous arguments.

```
def complicatedfunction(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6):
    '''This requires 6 pieces of info'''

    return ((arg1 + arg2) / (arg3 * arg4)) ** (arg5 + arg6)
```

In this case, you are making unreadable code, and you should reduce the number of arguments to **5 or less**.

**Reducing Argument Counts**

In this case, you could pass a namedtuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Numbers = namedtuple("Numbers", "numerator denominator exponent")
mynumber = Numbers(1+2, 3+4, 5+6)

def complicatedfunction(number):
    return (number.numerator / number.denominator) ** (number.exponent)
```

This has the added benefit of then making your code easy to modify in the future. Say I need to add another argument: I can just add that as a value into the namedtuple.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Numbers = namedtuple("Numbers", "numerator denominator exponent add")
mynumber = Numbers(1+2, 3+4, 5+6, 2)

def complicatedfunction(number):
    value = (number.numerator / number.denominator) ** (number.exponent)
    return value + number.add
```

**Object-Oriented Design**

Or, if I want to use that specific namedtuple for a lot of different tasks, I can subclass it and then get a 0-argument method for a specific goal. I can add as many methods as I want, which allows me to use the object in a versatile manner, as follows:

```
from collections import namedtuple


class Numbers(namedtuple("Numbers", "numerator denominator exponent add")):

    def process(self):
        value = (self.numerator / self.denominator) ** (self.exponent)
        return value + self.add

mynumber = Numbers(1+2, 3+4, 5+6, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use default argument method

```
def add_two(x=0):
    return x + 2
>>> add_two(1)
3
>>> add_two()
2
>>>
```